# Assigning UUID and checking duplicates for web scraper in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, web-scraping, scrapy, pymongo

I am building a web scraper and trying to assign an entity a UUID.

Since one entity may be scraped at different times, I want to store the initial UUID along with the extracted id from the webpage

```
// example document
{
 "ent_eid_type": "ABC-123", 
 "ent_uid_type": "123e4567-aaa-123e456" 
}
```

below is code that runs for every id field that is found in a scraped item

```
 # if the current ent_eid_type is a key in mongo...
if db_coll.find({ent_eid_type: ent_eid}).count() > 0:

     # return the uid value  
    ent_uid = db_coll.find({ent_uid_type: ent_uid })
else:
     # create a fresh uid 
    ent_uid = uuid.uuid4()

     # store it with the current entity eid as key, and uid as value
    db_coll.insert({ent_eid_type: ent_eid, ent_uid_type: ent_uid})

# update the current item with the stored uid for later use   
item[ent_uid_type] = ent_uid
```

Console is returning `KeyError: <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x104d41710>`. Not sure how to parse the cursor for the `ent_uid`

Any tips/ suggests appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pymongo Find command returns a **cursor** object you need to iterate or access to get the object

Access the first result (you already checked one exists), and access the ent_uid field.

Presumably, you're going to search on EID type, with ent_eid not ent_uid.  No reason to search if you already have it.

```
ent_uid = db_coll.find({ent_eid_type: ent_eid })[0]['ent_uid']
```

or don't worry about the cursor and use the **find_one** command instead (http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one)

```
ent_uid = db_coll.find_one({ent_eid_type: ent_eid })['ent_uid']
```